# Application Virtualization: How application streaming can be done via internet?

Tags: windows, streaming, profiling, virtualization, packaging

I know about packing a software as a virtual application through application virtualization products. But I really dont understand, How can they offer the streaming services of a package from a centralized server to the clients.

They call it as application streaming. Can someone explain it how that can be done.

Comment: Why did you tag it as C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it's just virtualization, with bits delivered on-demand in the most optimal way possible.